# Globalization not returning all culture nationalites as expected. .NET C# Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, globalization

I am compiling a list of all the nationalities in the world so that my users can select their nationality from a dropdown and display this in a bio. I decided to use globalisation for this.

whenever i load the following code the output is different to what is expected according to the documentation listed here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.culturetypes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

the code below line for line following the documentation is.

```cs
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
{
    Console.Write("{0,-7}", ci.Name);
    Console.Write(" {0,-3}", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    Console.Write(" {0,-3}", ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
    Console.Write(" {0,-3}", ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName);
    Console.Write(" {0,-40}", ci.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine(" {0,-40}", ci.EnglishName);
}
```

Documentation output is.

```
CULTURE ISO ISO WIN DISPLAYNAME                              ENGLISHNAME
ar      ar  ara ARA Arabic                                   Arabic
bg      bg  bul BGR Bulgarian                                Bulgarian
ca      ca  cat CAT Catalan                                  Catalan
zh-Hans zh  zho CHS Chinese (Simplified)                     Chinese (Simplified)
cs      cs  ces CSY Czech                                    Czech
da      da  dan DAN Danish                                   Danish
de      de  deu DEU German                                   German
el      el  ell ELL Greek                                    Greek
en      en  eng ENU English                                  English
es      es  spa ESP Spanish                                  Spanish
fi      fi  fin FIN Finnish                                  Finnish
zh      zh  zho CHS Chinese                                  Chinese
zh-Hant zh  zho CHT Chinese (Traditional)                    Chinese (Traditional)
zh-CHS  zh  zho CHS Chinese (Simplified) Legacy              Chinese (Simplified) Legacy
zh-CHT  zh  zho CHT Chinese (Traditional) Legacy             Chinese (Traditional) Legacy
```

My output is

```
CULTURE ISO ISO WIN DISPLAYNAME                              ENGLISHNAME
blazor.webassembly.js:1         iv  ivl IVL und                                      Invariant Language (Invariant Country)  
blazor.webassembly.js:1 de      de  deu DEU de                                       de                                      
blazor.webassembly.js:1 en      en  eng ENU en                                       en                                      
blazor.webassembly.js:1 es      es  spa ESN es                                       es                                      
blazor.webassembly.js:1 fr      fr  fra FRA fr                                       fr                                      
blazor.webassembly.js:1 it      it  ita ITA it                                       it
```

I have a much shortened and abbreviated list every time I try to use globalisation and have tried several ways. Has anyone any idea as to why this is occurring? I have resorted to just coding the list manually so that users can select nationality and store for later. although I have posted this in case I need to use globalisation later. I tested this on both incognito and open browser and the same result occurs.

Many thanks.

Mitch.

//EDIT enum for nationalities below if needed.

for anyone who came here with the same issue and just wants a list of all the nationalities of each country. here is the list below. NOTE I have substituted hyphens for "HH" and spaces for "_". target these and convert in your code for UI purposes if need be.

```
 public enum Nationality{
            Afghan=1,
            Albanian=2,
            Algerian=3,
            American=4,
            Andorran=5,
            Angolan=6,
            Antiguans=7,
            Argentinean=8,
            Armenian=9,
            Australian=10,
            Austrian=11,
            Azerbaijani=12,
            Bahamian=13,
            Bahraini=14,
            Bangladeshi=15,
            Barbadian=16,
            Barbudans=17,
            Batswana=18,
            Belarusian=19,
            Belgian=20,
            Belizean=21,
            Beninese=22,
            Bhutanese=23,
            Bolivian=24,
            Bosnian=25,
            Brazilian=26,
            British=27,
            Bruneian=28,
            Bulgarian=29,
            Burkinabe=30,
            Burmese=31,
            Burundian=32,
            Cambodian=33,
            Cameroonian=34,
            Canadian=35,
            Cape_Verdean=36,
            Central_African=37,
            Chadian=38,
            Chilean=39,
            Chinese=40,
            Colombian=41,
            Comoran=42,
            Congolese=43,
            Costa_Rican=44,
            Croatian=45,
            Cuban=46,
            Cypriot=47,
            Czech=48,
            Danish=49,
            Djibouti=50,
            Dominican=51,
            Dutch=52,
            East_Timorese=53,
            Ecuadorean=54,
            Egyptian=55,
            Emirian=56,
            Equatorial_Guinean=57,
            Eritrean=58,
            Estonian=59,
            Ethiopian=60,
            Fijian=61,
            Filipino=62,
            Finnish=63,
            French=64,
            Gabonese=65,
            Gambian=66,
            Georgian=67,
            German=68,
            Ghanaian=69,
            Greek=70,
            Grenadian=71,
            Guatemalan=72,
            GuineaHHBissauan=73,
            Guinean=74,
            Guyanese=75,
            Haitian=76,
            Herzegovinian=77,
            Honduran=78,
            Hungarian=79,
            IHHKiribati=80,
            Icelander=81,
            Indian=82,
            Indonesian=83,
            Iranian=84,
            Iraqi=85,
            Irish=86,
            Israeli=87,
            Italian=88,
            Ivorian=89,
            Jamaican=90,
            Japanese=91,
            Jordanian=92,
            Kazakhstani=93,
            Kenyan=94,
            Kittian_and_Nevisian=95,
            Kuwaiti=96,
            Kyrgyz=97,
            Laotian=98,
            Latvian=99,
            Lebanese=100,
            Liberian=101,
            Libyan=102,
            Liechtensteiner=103,
            Lithuanian=104,
            Luxembourger=105,
            Macedonian=106,
            Malagasy=107,
            Malawian=108,
            Malaysian=109,
            Maldivian=110,
            Malian=111,
            Maltese=112,
            Marshallese=113,
            Mauritanian=114,
            Mauritian=115,
            Mexican=116,
            Micronesian=117,
            Moldovan=118,
            Monacan=119,
            Mongolian=120,
            Moroccan=121,
            Mosotho=122,
            Motswana=123,
            Mozambican=124,
            Namibian=125,
            Nauruan=126,
            Nepalese=127,
            New_Zealander=128,
            NiHHVanuatu=129,
            Nicaraguan=130,
            Nigerian=131,
            Nigerien=132,
            North_Korean=133,
            Northern_Irish=134,
            Norwegian=135,
            Omani=136,
            Pakistani=137,
            Palauan=138,
            Panamanian=139,
            Papua_New_Guinean=140,
            Paraguayan=141,
            Peruvian=142,
            Polish=143,
            Portuguese=144,
            Qatari=145,
            Romanian=146,
            Russian=147,
            Rwandan=148,
            Saint_Lucian=149,
            Salvadoran=150,
            Samoan=151,
            San_Marinese=152,
            Sao_Tomean=153,
            Saudi=154,
            Scottish=155,
            Senegalese=156,
            Serbian=157,
            Seychellois=158,
            Sierra_Leonean=159,
            Singaporean=160,
            Slovakian=161,
            Slovenian=162,
            Solomon_Islander=163,
            Somali=164,
            South_African=165,
            South_Korean=166,
            Spanish=167,
            Sri_Lankan=168,
            Sudanese=169,
            Surinamer=170,
            Swazi=171,
            Swedish=172,
            Swiss=173,
            Syrian=174,
            Taiwanese=175,
            Tajik=176,
            Tanzanian=177,
            Thai=178,
            Togolese=179,
            Tongan=180,
            Trinidadian_or_Tobagonian=181,
            Tunisian=182,
            Turkish=183,
            Tuvaluan=184,
            Ugandan=185,
            Ukrainian=186,
            Uruguayan=187,
            Uzbekistani=188,
            Venezuelan=189,
            Vietnamese=190,
            Welsh=191,
            Yemenite=192,
            Zambian=193,
            Zimbabwean=194,
        }
```

Comment: Don't edit an answer into your question, you can post  a self-answer below.

Comment: it isn't an answer... it's a workaround. not an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Set the `BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData` property to true in the app's project file (.csproj):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>    
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly)

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Thanks how we can use it?

Comment: This has only added more entries but not corrected the issue of getting the actual region names. like Australia, Germany etc